# Long running copy to bytes.Buffer

Tags: go, io, buffer

I have a long lived `io.Reader` which returns some data every few seconds (never EOF), and a goroutine which does an `io.Copy` from that reader to a `bytes.Buffer` (also never terminates). Something like so:

```
var src io.Reader
var buf bytes.Buffer

func main() {
    go io.Copy(&buf, src)
    // Do stuff. Read from the buffer periodically.
}
```

What I don't understand is that I see strange results when I try to read from that buffer. It doesn't matter whether I call `buf.Bytes()` or `ioutil.ReadAll(&buf)` or anything, I just see the first bytes written to the buffer over and over again.

https://play.golang.org/p/yn0JPrvohV

My question is, what am I doing wrong? Can I use `bytes.Buffer` in this way (`io.Copy` to it and read periodically)?

Comment: There's a data race on the bytes.Buffer. Run your application [with the race detector](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html).

Comment: Also, describe the higher-level problem you are trying to solve.  The best solution to that problem may not involve a bytes.Buffer.

Comment: Besides the data race conditions, there isn't any logical synchronization between the copy goroutine and the reading goroutine, so the program may exit before the the reads are complete, or your copy function could write to the buffer between the Read and Reset calls, losing data. You need synchronization between the read and the write loops, or they need to be on opposite sides of a FIFO, like an io.Pipe. (You also don't ever need single-case select statements)

Comment: @MellowMarmot I've updated the example with a new one that doesn't have a race.

Comment: @JimB Take a look at the new example. I'm basically looking for some buffer where I can keep writing things perpetually, and then at some point, read what I've buffered so far. bytes.Buffer doesn't seem to be doing what I want it to here. I've actually solved this now for my specific problem using a bufio.Writer, but I still don't understand why the bytes.Buffer approach wouldn't work.

Comment: @Dave: see the first comment, you have a race condition on the bytes.Buffer.

Comment: @Dave Copy the code in the playground to main.go and `go run -race main.go`.   You will see there's still a race.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't synchronize your Read calls with the writes that are happening on the `bytes.Buffer` in the `io.Copy`. Even if you wrap the `bytes.Buffer` in a struct to lock the Read/Write methods, you are going to deadlock when the Copy is waiting on a Write while the ReadAll is blocked on the Read. You either need to do the copy manually, and properly serialize all access, or separate the reads and writes with an `io.Pipe`.

If you use a FIFO (`io.Pipe`) to synchronize reads and writes, you don't need any extra locks or channels to tail the first `io.Reader`. Here's an example `read` function that either prints when its buffer is full, or waits some interval since the last print statement:

```
func read(r io.Reader) {
    buf := make([]byte, 1024)
    pos := 0
    lastPrint := time.Now()
    for {
        n, err := r.Read(buf[pos:])
        if n > 0 {
            pos += n
        }

        if pos >= len(buf) || time.Since(lastPrint) > 125*time.Millisecond && pos > 0 {
            fmt.Println("read:", buf[:pos])
            lastPrint = time.Now()
            pos = 0
        }

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            break
        }
    }

    if pos > 0 {
        fmt.Println("read:", buf[:pos])
    }
}

func main() {
    pr, pw := io.Pipe()
    go func() {
        io.Copy(pw, &trickle{})
        pw.Close()
    }()
    read(pr)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/8NeV3v0LOU

Comment: Thanks for this. This is a much smarter way of solving the problem. :) I think if I need to do a long running io.Copy again, I will definitely use a pipe, rather than bytes.Buffer, especially since it isn't safe for concurrent access, which I didn't realise initially. I can buffer on the other end of the pipe then.

Comment: @Dave: it's good to note that _no_ data structures in Go are safe for concurrent access, unless specifically documented as such.